# Method to wrap value in Ok

Tags: rust

I want to wrap value in Ok like this

```rust
12.ok()
```

Am I able to do this or I can only use `Ok(12)`?

Comment: Why would `12.ok()` be preferable to `Ok(12)`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because to answer it you just need to try it, see it doesn't work, and done.

Comment: @isaactfa I have 16 lines long method that wrapped in Ok like `Ok(value...` with methods chain on newlines after value. Because of `Ok(` part the indentation is a little bit broken and extra parens added. With `.ok()` method it would look nicer. I also ask this question because I am new to Rust, I wonder if it has "extension methods" like in Kotlin/Scala.

Comment: @BlackBeans I am new to Rust, so thanks you for your welcomeness. I want to know if this possible in any way (not only THIS way). Now I know (thanks to isaactfa) that it can be done with traits.

Comment: @MaxSmirnov It would be better to split the return into two lines then: `let result = very.long().method().chain(); return Ok(result);`.

Comment: @MaxSmirnov I've amended my answer to outline why this is a bad idea. I recommend you read over it again.

Comment: rust-analyzer provides a postfix completion for `ok`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would strongly recommend **against this**. `Result` is a very well known type in the Rust ecosystem with a lot of conventions, idioms and patterns. This is decidedly *not* one of them and will be confusing for anyone who comes across it, especially because [`Result::ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok) already is a method. So this is doubly terrible.
Just because you can do something, doesn't mean you should.

That warning said, you could do this:

```
trait Okable<Err> {
    fn ok(self) -> Result<Self, Err> where Self: Sized {
        Ok(self)
    }
}

impl<T, Err> Okable<Err> for T {}

fn main() {
    let _x: Result<_, ()> = 12.ok();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such detailed explanation. So it is preferable to wrap anything like `T(v)` rather than `n.t()`?

Comment: @MaxSmirnov Not in general, no. For example, you can get a `Some(v)` by calling `v.into()` because `From<T>` is implemented for `Option<T>` and that's perfectly fine to use. It's really the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) that comes into play here: Everybody who writes Rust knows how `Result` behaves and this trick upsets that expectation for little to no benefit. To make a general rule out of this: It's probably a bad idea to mess with the API of a standard library type unless there's a very good reason.